# Convergent subsequence implies continuous function attains minimum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(X,T)$ be compact and non-empty, then every sequence in $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ in $(X,T)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Using this I want to show the following:

If $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $(X,T)$-continuous, then $f$ attains its minimum on $X$. That is, there exists $\tilde{x} \in X$ such that $f(\tilde{x}) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

My attempt:

Let $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $(X,T)$ such that $|f(x_n) - \inf_{x\in X} f(x)| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. *How do I justify the existence of $(x_n)$?*

Since $(X,T)$ is compact, $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ has a convergent subsequence in $(X,T)$, say $(x_{n_k})_{k=0}^{\infty}$, denote the limit by $\tilde{x} \in X$. Then since $f$ is a continuous function $f(x_{n_k}) \rightarrow f(\tilde{x})$ in $(\mathbb{R},T_{\text{usual}})$.

Moreover, $\tilde{x}$ has the property we desire,  $f(\tilde{x}) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in X$. *How do I justify this?*

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to prove this is by first showing that $f$ continuous and $X$ compact, non-empty implies $f(X)$ is compact. Once you know $f(X)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, you will know by the Heine-Borel Theorem that $f(X)$ is closed and bounded. Since $f(X)$ is bounded, $\inf f(X)$ is a real number, and it will be a limit point of $f(X)$. Since $\inf f(X)$ is a limit point and $f(X)$ is closed (i.e. $f(X)$ contains its limit points), you will know that $\inf f(X)$ must be an element of $f(X)$. This proves the desired result since $\inf f(X) \in f(X) \iff \exists x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0) = \inf f(X)$.

So, let's show that $f$ continuous and $X$ compact implies $f(X)$ is compact. Let $b_n$ be a sequence in $f(X)$. This means that there is a corresponding sequence $a_n$ in $X$ with $f(a_n) = b_n$. Since $X$ is compact, $(a_n)$ has a convergent subsequence, say $(a_{n_i})_{i=1}^\infty$ converging to $a$. Then, I claim $(b_{n_i})$ is a convergent subsequence of $(b_n)$ converging to $f(a)$. We see that $$\lim_{i \to \infty} b_{n_i} = \lim_{i \to \infty} f(a_{n_i}) = f\left(\lim_{i \to \infty} (a_{n_i})\right) = f(a) $$

where the middle equality holds by the continuity of $f$. Hence, $f(X)$ is compact which implies the result by the discussion in the first paragraph.